# Polygon selection

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I'm using the WPF version of GMaps.net.  Certain functionalities such as polygon selection is not that obvious.

What I need to do is detect a polygon click on the map, and then change properties of the polygon (opacity etc) to show that it is selected.  A custom way to achieve this is by getting the mouse coordinates with a mouse click event, and do a polygon intersection test with some vector maths, however I'm sure there must be a built-in way to do this?

For clarity sake, this is how I create my polygons:

```
        GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(polyPointList);
        polygon.RegenerateShape(gMapControl1);
        (polygon.Shape as Path).Stroke = Brushes.DarkBlue;
        (polygon.Shape as Path).Opacity = 0.5;
        gMapControl1.Markers.Add(polygon);
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549857/how-to-respond-to-click-event-with-gmap-net-for-wpf/50007863#50007863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're right, the WPF version of the polygon doesn't offer it right out of the box.

Think you could use the `PointLatLng` of your click and check if that's within the bounds of the polygon. Take [the WinForms version of it](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapPolygon.cs#L241) and adapt it. In the end it's just that bit of math that's lacking.